# Java: How to pass a variable into function with interface parameter type

Tags: java

Assume class `A` implements interface `B`, is it possible to pass `List<A>` into a function with parameter `List<B>`:

```
List<A> var1;
```

how to call (with some fix): `func(var1)`

```
void func(List<B> var){
}
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It did not work, eclipse did not allow.. it mentioned I need to change to `func(List<A> var)`

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible (at least, not without some grotesque casting). One is not the supertype of the other.

Answer (score 1):

Sure:  `func(Collections.<B>unmodifiableList(var1))`.  As long as you can guarantee that the list isn't being modified, that sort of call is safe.

Comment: I don't think this is a grotesque cast at all. The only way I knew so far was to declare `func(List<? extends B> lb)` but this can be done on call-site which is very useful.

Comment: It's not a grotesque cast.  You're wrapping the original object in a completely different type of object.  It's _something_, but I wouldn't call it casting.

Comment: The OP's question did not specify "casting."  I call it fair game.

Answer (score 0):

No.  `List<A>` is not a subtype of `List<B>`.

The reason is that if you have a `List<B>`, you can add objects to it whose class is any implementation of `B`.  You can't do that to a `List<A>`.  So there are operations that are fine for a `List<B>` but not a `List<A>`; which means that a `List<A>` can't possibly be a kind of `List<B>`.

What you actually want, I think, is to use `List<? extends B>` as the type of your parameter, instead of `List<B>`.

Answer (score 0):

What a strange idea, trying to by-pass type checks.

Do classes A and B have the same properties ? If yes, consider copying them by
org.apache.commons.beanutils.**BeanUtils.copyProperties**(src,dest) and wrap the List argument in some conversion method.

If you insist on passing something generally incompatible, something like this should work because of **type erasure**:

```
List x = var1;
func(x);
```